# Octave: class and function file names

Tags: function, octave, classname

When I create a class or a function file in octave. Is there a possibility to give the file a name that is different from the classes/functions name? (Class *test* is in the file *test.m*, but i would prefer to name the file for example *test.class.m*)

```
# test.m
classdef test
  % ...
endclassdef
```

Comment: I would add to Andrew's answer by saying that Octave has limited support for so-called "new-style" matlab classes using the classdef system, and instead prefers (and optimizes) the "old-style" system, relying on "@folders". See [the relevant manual section](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Object-Oriented-Programming.html#Object-Oriented-Programming) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The way Octave is designed, classes and functions must be defined in files whose file names exactly match the class or function name. This is so that, given a function or class name, Octave knows where to locate its definition on disk, so it can lazily load in their definitions as they are needed by other source code, instead of having to load the entire source tree up front.

The exception is "command-line" functions, where you can define global functions inside a script, and their definition appears when the script is executed. This isn't a good way to organize code for larger projects, though, because you'd need to arrange for execution of all the scripts at the appropriate time, before those function definitions are needed.

If you want to distinguish classes from functions, you have the option of sticking them in subdirectories named `@<class>`, for example, `@test/test.m`.

Comment: Meanwhile octave supports [`classdef` classes](https://www.google.com/search?q=octave+classdef). Note that google won't tell you as much if you don't know about it yet -- the top results in Google for "octave class" or "octave object oriented programming" all point to documentation for an outdated version, predating `classdef` support.

Comment: That is an issue with Octave's googlejuice: too much of it is pointing to old versions, and while there's a "doc/current/" URL set up, it's a redirect to the then-current version, so I think the googlejuice accrues to that particular version. There's been some discussion of this on the Octave Maintainers mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/octave-maintainers/2020-07/msg00006.html

For me, the #2 and #4 Google hits for "octave class" are in fact "classdef Classes (Octave 4.4.1)". Is that not showing up for you?

Comment: Now it does, as #2. Could have been the same before. I may be a bit too accustomed to Google giving the right priorities, and first assumed the first results gives a complete picture... With python the issue is more obvious due to the Py2/Py3 dichotomy, and due to help pages containing a "select python version" drop-down menu.